# How to convert a local socks server into a local interface?

Tags: proxy, interface, socks

Exist a way to convert a local socks proxy into a local interface? My problem is that some application don't have the possibility to specify a socks proxy, and I need that all my communication pass through my local socks proxy.

Answer (score 5):

Presenting a network interface would be only partially useful - as routing is accomplished based on the destination address and not the source address or the interface a socket is bound to (with the notable exception of using alternate routing tables), simply having a socksified interface would not make your processes send requests through it.

For Linux platforms, running [`socksify <application>`](http://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.2.x/socksify.1.html) is going to give you what you want - transparent SOCKS proxying. The `socksify` script and the accompanying binaries are part of the [DANTE](http://www.inet.no/dante/) package. There also is the possibility of [*socksifying* all processes run](http://www.inet.no/dante/doc/faq.html#socksify_system) on a Linux host by installing DANTE and setting LD_PRELOAD in .bashrc appropriately:

```
LD_PRELOAD="libdl.so libdsocks.so"
export LD_PRELOAD
```

Comment: Eeeew. LD_PRELOAD.  Seriously deep magic right there.  Have a +1

Answer (score 4):

While I haven't tried either of these myself, [`tun2socks`](https://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks) or [`redsocks`](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/) seem to do what you're looking for. `tun2socks` actually creates a new interface, e.g., `tun0`. I don't think `redsocks` does, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/) or [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/) to send all traffic from specific applications via a SOCKS server.

Comment: +1 for the principle, although `tsocks´ is horribly old and no longer updated and newer, maintained implementations (DANTE comes to mind) are surely to be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [privoxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privoxy). It is a proxy server that can talk to a socks proxy. You need to change privoxy configuration file to include a line like:

```
forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

In this example, it forwards all requests it receives to SOCKS v5 proxy on localhost port 9050.

Comment: How it receive the requests? It create a new interface?

Comment: @frankabel: It presents a normal HTTP proxy interface.

Comment: That is not what I'm finding, I need something that be transparent to clients programs, as I said, some client programmers don't have the capability to specify socks proxy (neither any other kind of proxy), but still I want the communication of those problem go through my local socks proxy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers seem to me that is what I need, now the problem is what is the best of those available options ;)

Comment: @frankabel just take your criteria and match against the featuregrids in the referenced Wikipedia article. Or, if this would not do for you, test several of them by yourself.